# How access elements in wso2?

Tags: json, wso2, element, esb, wso2-esb

I want to access "email" element in wso2 , "25" and "26" are not fixed , can you please help ? thanks

```
   {
    "sending": {
        "25": [
            {
               
                "email": "aa@hotmail.com",
                "name": "jack"
            }
        ],
        "26": [
            {
                "email": "aa@hotmail.com",
                "name": "jack"
            },
            {
                "email": "aa@hotmail.com",
                "name": "jack"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to take a look at JSONPath.

Are you going to get All the emails at once? then use:

`<property expression="json-eval($.sending.*.[*].email)" name="emails"/>`

else?

use @Shanaka Premarathna `s answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. The first expression will capture the first two email addresses and the second expression will capture the last email address.

```
         <log>
            <property expression="json-eval($.sending.*.[0].email)" name="email->1,2"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.sending.*.[1].email)" name="email->3"/>
         </log>
```